# Fetching multiple xml file from folder

Tags: python, xml, sqlite

i am working with ncbi pubmed ftp data i have to parse xml

i have stored xml file in folder approx 1500 (250 gb) files are stored in folder i am reading file from folder , but in my code when i run  it my system getting freezed .how to solve it

```
import sqlite3 
import os 
import lxml.etree as ET 


path = '/home/shayez/Desktop/Ex'

listfile = []
files = os.listdir(path)
for name in files:

listfile.append(name)


pmdata = []    

for name2 in listfile:
    full_file = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('Ex',name2))
    dom = ET.parse(full_file)
    pmdat = dom.findall('PubmedArticle')
    pmdata.append(pmdat)         


conn = sqlite3.connect('/home/shayez/Desktop/NewNCBI')
co = conn.cursor()
print ("Opened database successfully")

for d in pmdata:
  for c in d :
    PMID = c.find('MedlineCitation/PMID').text
    title = c.find('MedlineCitation/Article/ArticleTitle').text
    Date = 
c.find('MedlineCitation/Article/Journal/JournalIssue/PubDate/Year')
    Date2 = 
c.find('MedlineCitation/Article/Journal/JournalIssue/PubDate/MedlineDate')
    Abstract = c.find('MedlineCitation/Article/Abstract/AbstractText')
    if Abstract is None :
         pass
    elif Date is None:
        example =[(PMID,Date2.text,Abstract.text)]
        co.executemany('INSERT INTO pubdata(PMID,Date,Abstract)  VALUES (?,?,?)',example)
    else:
        example =[(PMID,Date.text,Abstract.text)]
        co.executemany('INSERT INTO pubdata(PMID,Date,Abstract)  VALUES (?,?,?)',example)

conn.commit()
print("Records Save Successfully")
conn.close()
```